# How to use delimiter to find the end of the line?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am trying to read this pattern... What is the `Scanner.useDelimiter` for this?

This input is:

> 489 490-1; 491-1; 492-1; 493-1; 494-1; 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   490 491-1; 492-1; 493-1; 494-1; 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   491 492-1; 493-1; 494-1; 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   492 493-1; 494-1; 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   493 494-1; 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   494 495-1; 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   495 496-1; 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   496 497-1; 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;
>   497 498-1; 499-1; 500-1;

What I need is to put 489, 490, 491 in One array of control and 490 ,1 ,491, 1(second column and them) in one collection.

I tried this delimiter but it didn't work:
`Scanner(readerFile).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");`

Because he stays in loop in my `while(readerFile.hasNextInt())` and don't call the `nextLine()` function, reading all the inputs in the collection.

```
while (readerFile.hasNextLine()){
   readerFile.nextLine();
   vector[i] = readerFile.nextInt();
   while (readerFile.hasNextInt()){
       linkedList.add(reader.nextInt());
   }
}
```

How to control the next line?

Comment: Once the tags are removed from the title, there's really no title remaining. [Should Questions include tags in the title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190)

Comment: `useDelimiter` doesn't affect `nextLine` behavior, afaik. When you call nextLine, the whole line will be consumed (and in your case, since you don't assign it to a variable, it is thrown away)

Comment: yes, yes, but i want to read all the inputs variable(489), collection (490 1 491 1 492 1  493 1  494 1 495 1  496 1  497 1  498 1  499 1  500 1) and after that I need to go to the next line. If i cant control and dont call next line he stays reading the next int in the collection, understand?

Comment: It's a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it this way:

Pseudocode:

```
While has next line
    s = next line
    split = s.split(" ", 2);
    vector[i] = split[0]; // or whatever you want to do with the first value
    values = split[1].split(";")
    foreach value in values
        linkedList.add(value); // or whatever you want to do with the rest of the values
```

Comment: I dont got it here, after the ; there's a white space, don't cause error in the first split?

Comment: @NicolasBontempo The first split is done using `split(" ", 2)`, which limits the amount of parts to two, i.e. only splits on the first space

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, i will try and come back to reply if work (: